# eslint not ignoring node_modules and getting error when try to lint

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, eslint, eslintignore

I'm trying to implement `eslint` in a `Next.js` project.The file structure look like below

```
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.js
.next
.prettierrc
.stylelintrc.js
components
forms
modals
modules
node_modules
```

And I have `node_modules/*` in my `.eslintignore` file. When I try to lint these by `eslint --fix /sources/**/*.js` I am getting below error

```
You are linting "/sources/node_modules/ally.js", but all of the files matching the glob pattern "/sources/node_modules/ally.js" are ignored.
```

Anyone can help me to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `**/node_modules/*`?

Comment: Yes. But gives the same error.

Comment: try `./node_modules`

Comment: @enoch no use. Same error.

Comment: try to delete `node_modules` and `.next` folder then reinstall with them with `npm install`.

Comment: I saw [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12344) that could be related

Comment: @enoch no use. Same error.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Tnx I will check this.

Comment: @Rich if your project is not private, you can share a repo or codesandbox link , so i can check that

Comment: @enoch Sorry I can't do that. It is a private project.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might come from your command line.

If you forget the single quotes, **your terminal** is going to evaluate the glob (`**/*`), not `eslint`. So **this will skip all eslint ignore settings**.

If you enable `eslint`'s debug logs with `--debug`, you will see it in action:

- **Without** single quotes:

```bash
$ eslint **/*.ts --debug 2>&1 | grep "CLI args"

eslint:cli CLI args: [ 'a.ts', 'b.ts', 'node_modules/package/a.ts', 'node_modules/package/b.ts', '--debug' ]
```

- **With** single quotes:

```bash
$ eslint '**/*.ts' --debug 2>&1 | grep "CLI args"

eslint:cli CLI args: [ '**/*.ts', '--debug' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.eslintignore` located in the same directory as `node_modules` you can specify it as `node_modules`.

```
# .eslintignore
node_modules
**/.next/**
**/_next/**
**/dist/**
```

`.eslintignore` follows `.gitignore` syntax.
See [.gitignore specs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more details.

Comment: Got the same error for mentioned `.eslintignore`

Can you check it once?

Answer (score 0):

linters dosnt work same with diffrent node versions

in this case updating node to `v16.x` from `v14.x` worked for me.

---

if ignorefile config dosnt work for you. check your node version.