# eslint ignore pattern not works

Tags: node.js, eslint, lint

I want to run lint check all the file *.js without node_modules

Here my command: `"lint": "eslint **/*.js",`, My folder structure look like: `app > module_name > module.js` but in the app folder still having some files common like `helpers.js` `server.js` and I also want to check them.

In .eslint config I added `"ignorePatterns": "node_modules"` and tried added a file .eslintignore and add `node_modules` but it's not working.

When I run `npm run lint` it always throw error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.32.0

You are linting "node_modules/bignumber.js", but all of the files matching the glob pattern "node_modules/bignumber.js" are ignored.

If you don't want to lint these files, remove the pattern "node_modules/bignumber.js" from the list of arguments passed to ESLint.

If you do want to lint these files, try the following solutions:

* Check your .eslintignore file, or the eslintIgnore property in package.json, to ensure that the files are not configured to be ignored.
* Explicitly list the files from this glob that you'd like to lint on the command-line, rather than providing a glob as an argument.
```

Comment: correct answer https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12344#issuecomment-536775251

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75877957/3970387

Answer (score 2):

You could add `node_modules/` in your .eslintignore file, and update the package.json file with script: `"lint": "eslint --ext .js app/",` before running `npm run lint`.

Comment: If I change only script, it works. But If I change only .eslintignore, it doesn't work. Because if script is correct, eslint checks only in /app folder and node_modules is not inside /app folder, no need to add node_modules to .eslintignore. If my script is not correct, It checks all filter from root folder, and I add node_modules to .eslint ignore, why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

You could add `node_modules/` in your `.eslintignore` file, and update the `package.json` file with script:
if u r using ubuntu/linux

```
"lint": "eslint '**/*.js'"
```

if project structure like these `folder/file.js`

if u r using windows

```
"lint": "eslint **/*.js"
```

if project structure like these `folder/file.js`